# File comparison using ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to compare 2 different files and show the difference between those two files.

I looked it up online and got this answer from https://github.com/samg/diffy but i am getting this error message

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Diffy

from (irb):11

from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Has someone already encountered this problem before? THX

Comment: Did you `require diffy` before trying it out?

Comment: Thanks. I am testing it on terminal. Don't think I need those.
corrrect me if I am wrong..

Comment: Also, make sure that you `gem install diffy`.

Comment: yes already @ArchimedesPi

Comment: As someone who stepped away from ruby a few years ago, who's only just picking it up again _for diffing purposes_, this Q&A turned out to be exactly what I needed. (Why on earth did someone downvote it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had this issue when I was testing this in my terminal.
**`require 'diffy'`** in terminal has solved my problem.